# React jsx: Cannot find module '' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) after updating NodeJS from 12 LTS to 18 LTS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I updated NodeJS from v12.22.9, (npm 6.14.15) (the default Ubuntu 22 comes with) to the `LTS`, version v18.12.0 which also comes with npm 8.19.2

I just opened VSC and all of my components have this warning for various imports:

```js
import WhiteLogo from "assets/img/GEF-logo-white.png";
import GreenLogo from "assets/img/GEF-logo-green.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Twitter } from "assets/icons/twitter.svg";
import styles from "./OverviewBanner.module.css";

Cannot find module 'assets/img/logo-white.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find module 'assets/img/logo-green.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find module 'assets/icons/twitter.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Cannot find module './OverviewBanner.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I am using React and JS.

This is the `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "antd": "^4.23.3",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.3"
  },
```

There is a file: `/node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts` that looks like this:

```
/// <reference types="node" />
/// <reference types="react" />
/// <reference types="react-dom" />

declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    readonly NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production' | 'test';
    readonly PUBLIC_URL: string;
  }
}

declare module '*.avif' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.bmp' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.gif' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.jpeg' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.webp' {
    const src: string;
    export default src;
}

declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<
    SVGSVGElement
  > & { title?: string }>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.module.css' {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

declare module '*.module.scss' {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

declare module '*.module.sass' {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

New File `env.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const src: string
  export const ReactComponent: unknown
  export default src
}
declare module '*.png' {
  const src: string
  export default src
}
type CSSModuleClasses = { readonly [key: string]: string }

declare module '*.module.css' {
  const classes: CSSModuleClasses
  export default classes
}
```

Comment: I have a file `/node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts` that has declarations similar to what you wrote. I will modify the OP with this information.